# GRANT user with select clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Have two tables : Applicant , Applies

```
//APPLICANT
A#
-------------
1
2
3
4  
5

//APPLIES
A#           POSITION
---------------------
1              GM
2             CEO
3             DIRECTOR
3             MANAGER
```

So i create the user like this:

```
CREATE USER TEST IDENTIFIED BY TESTING;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO TEST;
```

Now i want grant select to TEST on table APPLICANT which have at least 1 record in APPLIES table using follow query:

```
SELECT a.A#,COUNT(a.A#) FROM APPLICANT a 
  INNER JOIN APPLIES ap ON a.A#=ap.A# 
  HAVING COUNT(a.A#)>0 GROUP BY a.A#;
```

how i grant to user TEST? with select clause condition

```
GRANT SELECT ON APPLICANT WHERE (SELECT.......) TO TEST;
```

Fail to work, errors come out.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: AFAIK you can't grant access conditionally - you either grant the access, or you don't. One thing you *could* do would be to use your SQL above to create a view, then grant SELECT access on the view to TEST. Not sure if this would satisfy your requirement or not. Best of luck.